# How to run opencv_traincascade?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, object-detection, image-recognition, haar-classifier

I am having some trouble with `opencv_traincascade` this may trace back to earlier method calls, however I am not 100% sure.

```
opencv_traincascade -data classifier -vec samples.vec -bg 
negatives.txt -numStages 20 -minHitRate - 0.999 -maxFalseAlarmRate 0.5 
-numPos 4000 -numNeg 200000 -w 17 -h 23 -mode ALL 
-precalcValBufSize 1024 -precalcIdxBufSize 1024

error:

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I am following along with this [tutorial](https://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html). However, I have 5000 positive images and 200000 negative images to work from. So, Instead I followed this [link](http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html#e5c54f60) and I am using the method to create training samples from some instead of distorting a single image.

Create Samples:

```
opencv_createsamples -info positives.dat -vec samples.vec -w 17 -h 23 
-num 5000

Output:

    Info file name: positives.dat
    Img file name: (NULL)
    Vec file name: samples.vec
    BG  file name: (NULL)
    Num: 5000
    BG color: 0
    BG threshold: 80
    Invert: FALSE
    Max intensity deviation: 40
    Max x angle: 1.1
    Max y angle: 1.1
    Max z angle: 0.5
    Show samples: FALSE
    Width: 17
    Height: 23
    Max Scale: -1
```

I have viewed the sample images via the vec file with

```
opencv_createsamples -vec samples.vec -w 17 -h 23
```

If it is needed, a partial capture of positives.dat

```
    positive_images/0/18693.png 1 0 0 17 23
    positive_images/0/18501.png 1 0 0 17 23
    positive_images/0/19998.png 1 0 0 17 23
    positive_images/0/18224.png 1 0 0 17 23
    positive_images/0/19527.png 1 0 0 17 23
    positive_images/0/18739.png 1 0 0 17 23
    positive_images/0/6926.png 1 0 0 17 23
    positive_images/0/19520.png 1 0 0 17 23
    positive_images/0/7982.png 1 0 0 17 23
    positive_images/0/17458.png 1 0 0 17 23
    positive_images/0/17312.png 1 0 0 17 23
    positive_images/0/8497.png 1 0 0 17 23
```

I have searched a few different posts on Stack Overflow but the issues are slightly different than mine.

[thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22504258/opencv-createsamples-has-no-error-but-no-samples-found)

[thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14552167/opencv-traincascade-always-gets-stuck)

[thread3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36352206/what-are-the-recommended-parameters-for-opencv-traincascade)

I moved my windows machine over to a dual boot that is running the latest lts distro of Ubuntu.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. I wouldnt usually however stackoverflow was saying I had unformatted code present. Only way I could get the post up was to put in quote blocks.

Comment: Hmm, could be a bug, not sure. If it happens on a future request, ping a message [on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) where it can be investigated.

Comment: Will do thanks halfer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue! I created my negatives.dat file incorrectly so 1 issue was the negative files where not being found. Also I re-ran using the `opencv_traincascade` implementation [here](https://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html). only adjusting the amount of samples and the width and height of the image.

code from link

```
opencv_traincascade -data classifier -vec samples.vec -bg negatives.txt\
-numStages 20 -minHitRate 0.999 -maxFalseAlarmRate 0.5 -numPos 4500\
-numNeg 600 -w 17 -h 23 -mode ALL -precalcValBufSize 1024\
-precalcIdxBufSize 1024
```

While typing this I have just had a message pop up that says

```
Required leaf false alarm rate achieved. Branch training terminated.
```

Time to figure this out. Oh, it's not an error it is saying it did what I asked it to. Time to test this out.